# setCellValue not working

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i can't set the value of cell ,it works if i try this

```
if(1==1){
celltofill.setCellValue("test");
}
```

but once it enters the if condition it displays what's in syso but doesn't insert values in the cell.

any ideas about how can i solve this isssue?

here is my code:

```
public class testexcel {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, ParseException{

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\test6.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("D:\\edit6.xlsx");
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook.getSheetAt(1);


    for(int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        for(int i1=1;i1<sheet2.getLastRowNum();i1++){

        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        Cell cell =  row.getCell(2);    
        Row row2 = sheet2.getRow(i1);
        Cell cell2 =  row2.getCell(0);
        Cell celltofill= row.createCell(5);
        Cell cellres= row2.getCell(1);


        if((cell.getStringCellValue()).equals(cell2.getStringCellValue())){
            System.out.println((cell.getStringCellValue())+" equals "+cell2.getStringCellValue());
            celltofill.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            System.out.println("cell filled with "+cellres.getStringCellValue());
            celltofill.setCellValue(cellres.getStringCellValue());
        }

        }
    }

    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();


}
}
```

Comment: does it work if you remove `.setCellType();`?

Comment: no i tried removing it it didn't work

Comment: can you give us the values from the cells and whats printed?

Comment: CJXX equals CJXX
cell filled with DE
CLXX equals CLXX
cell filled with DE
EF50 equals EF50
cell filled with DE
EFXX equals EFXX
cell filled with OCP
FAXX equals FAXX
cell filled with OCL

Comment: what happens if you store the string from cellres in a variable and set the value from celltofill with the variable

Comment: @ XtremeBaumer it doesn't work either.  even this `if((cell.getStringCellValue()).equals(cell2.getStringCellValue())){celltofill.setCellValue("text")}` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

`row.createCell(5)` does exactly what it says. It creates a new empty cell every time it is called. And you are calling it for every row in `sheet2` again and again although it is a cell in `sheet`. So even if the criterions are not fullfilled, the new empty cell is been created already in your code.

Maybe:

...

```
for(int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
   Cell cell =  row.getCell(2);
   Cell celltofill= row.getCell(5);
   if (celltofill == null) celltofill = row.createCell(5);

   for(int i1=1;i1<sheet2.getLastRowNum();i1++){
    Row row2 = sheet2.getRow(i1);
    Cell cell2 =  row2.getCell(0);
    Cell cellres= row2.getCell(1);
```

...

will be more what you want?